# Do Windows 10 backward compatible with Windows 7 (API and drivers)?

Tags: windows-10-preview, windows-10-upgrade

MS announce free upgrade from Windows 7/8 to Windows 10 for non-corporate licences, from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/:

```
Get a free upgrade to Windows 10 starting July 29, 2015.
```

Is it safe to take this offer so any installed software and drivers would still work?

Is it possible to install and run without issues software that built for Windows XP/7/8 on Windows 10?

Is Windows 7 drivers compatible with Windows 10? I have out of life support hardware with drivers built for Windows 7...

Comment: You need to assess your own software, one piece at a time; there's no way for us to say "Yes it will all work" as there are far too many Windows applications. Contact your hardware vendor(s) and see if they have/plan on providing Windows 10 compatible drivers.

Comment: No;  The display model changed three times between Windows 7 and Windows 10.  Display drivers for Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8.0, and Windows 8.1 are NOT compatible with Windows 10.

Comment: The windows 10 installer will check and flag any potential hardware-driver issues before it actually installs the OS.

Comment: [This is what Microsoft said for the preview version](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-faq), not much will change for RTM. "Drivers for basic functions like storage, networking, input, and display come with Windows. These drivers allow you to complete the Windows installation and connect to the Internet. You might be able to get more drivers from Windows Update."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still wait Windows 10 but [MSDN win10 changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn932171.aspx) say about  new WDDM 2.0 driver model. It changes interaction with GPU, so at least I need adapted to Windows 10 driver for video card (( I believe that Windows know how to fall back to VESA spec to provide basic GUI experience.

Answer (score 2):

Compatibility between versions can never be guaranteed. It is safer to wait and, after launch, ask questions about your specific drivers if other haven't gone before you.

Alternatively, you could try to create a VM if the drivers will work in a VM. You will be able to get hold of trial versions of Windows 10 after launch and can download the beta now.